# Sentential Forms

Tags: logic

I have the following task: Determine which of the
following are statement forms. In each case when the given expression is
not a statement form, insert parentheses so that it becomes such a form.

1. $ ( P \rightarrow \lnot Q) \rightarrow (( \lnot (\lnot P)) \leftrightarrow  Q)  $
2. $(P  \rightarrow Q)  \rightarrow  R)  \rightarrow S)  \rightarrow T$
3. $(P  \rightarrow (\lnot Q   \rightarrow R )  \rightarrow Q)$
4. $((P  \rightarrow Q  \rightarrow R \land  Q) \lor (\lnot (P \lor Q))$

The first three seem reasonably straightforward .

1. $ ( P \rightarrow \lnot Q) \rightarrow (( \lnot (\lnot P)) \leftrightarrow  Q)  $ is a statement form
2. $(P  \rightarrow Q)  \rightarrow  R)  \rightarrow S)  \rightarrow T$ is not a statement form.

   However  $(((P  \rightarrow Q)  \rightarrow  R)  \rightarrow S)  \rightarrow T$ is.
3. $(P  \rightarrow (\lnot Q   \rightarrow R )  \rightarrow Q)$ is a statement form

Question  4  is slighty tougher. I think that it would not be a statement form, but am I unsure.

I am given the following rules: A statement letter is
a statement form of the simplest kind; and if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are statement
forms, then so are $ \lnot (S_1), (S_1) \land (S_2), (S_1) \lor (S_2), (S_1) \leftarrow (S2),$ and
$(S_1) \leftrightarrow (S_2)$. Parentheses may be omitted when confusion is unlikely.
Am I correct?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited the post.

Comment: Since your rules state that "parentheses may be omitted when confusion is *unlikely*" it would seem that you are not being asked to be absolutely precise in writing formulae.  However $P\to Q\to R$ is seriously ambiguous since $(P\to Q)\to R$ and $P\to(Q\to R)$ are not logically equivalent.  The continuation with "${}\wedge Q$" **might** be OK if you have been given some rules of precedence, but is probably also ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have at least to apply the rule about matching of parentheses. The example 2 :

> $(P→Q)→R)→S)→T$

is clearly **not** correct; the last two right parentheses are not matched. It must be :

> $(((P→Q)→R)→S)→T$.

Consider now example 4 :

> $((P→Q→R∧Q)∨(¬(P∨Q))$;

again, the parentheses are not matched: a right one is missing. In addition, we have ambiguity regarding the part : $(P→Q→R∧Q)$. In this case, the usual convention is : "grouping on the right". Thus we have to rewrite it as :

> $((P→(Q→(R∧Q)))∨(¬(P∨Q)))$.

But, applying the rule : "parentheses may be omitted when confusion is unlikely", we can more simply rewrite it as :

> $(P→(Q→(R∧Q)))∨(¬(P∨Q))$.